# Unable to override scrollViewDidScroll from UIScrollViewDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am new to iOS and swift, I was trying to override scrollViewDidScroll() from UIScrollViewDelegate but it was showing me "Method does not override any method from its superclass" , I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQ3CVd8-zNE

This is the code I did.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scrolliew: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    var contentWidth:CGFloat=0.0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrolliew.delegate=self
        
        for image in 0...3 {
            let imageToDisplay = UIImage(named:"\(image).png")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image:imageToDisplay)
            
            scrolliew.addSubview(imageView)
            
            let xCordinates = view.frame.minX + view.frame.width * CGFloat(image)
            
            contentWidth += view.frame.width
            
            imageView.frame=CGRect(x:xCordinates,y:view.frame.height/2,width:100,height:100)
            
        }
        
        scrolliew.contentSize=CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: view.frame.height)
    }
     

    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        //my code here
    }

}
```

Comment: If you continue watching that video, you'll see he gets the same error and eventually removes the `override` keyword. As a side note, that is a ***terrible*** way to approach this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to override the method. `scrollViewDidScroll(...)` is part of the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol whose implementation is optional.

*Just remove the override keyword in order to fix the error.*

Comment: yes I know, but I need to give its implementation of it as in the tutorial

Comment: If you notice, he does get the same error as you. This is the correct answer.